# RubyMineで when ~ then を一行で書く

Tags: ruby, rubymine

デフォルトでRubyMineの`Reformat`を使うと `when foo then bar` を一行で書いてると `bar`の部分が改行されてしまいます。

`when` で設定内を検索しても RubyのCodeStyleにヒットしないようですが、何かこの設定を変更する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらでも確認してみましたが、現状のRubyMineではカスタマイズできないようですね。
Issue trackerからnew featureをリクエストするぐらいしかないかもしれません。

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY

Comment: すいません、登録しようとして検索してから気づいたのですが2ヶ月ほど前に自分でIssue Trackerに申請してそのことを忘れておりました…。
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16931